# Need to improve JS function using a few || (logical or) or mayby another solution

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have function it works good but I want to improve that

```
  const canPrepareReview = (): boolean => {
if (loading) return true;
if (Object.keys(assets).length !== 0) return true;
return master;
```

}

```
  <Button
    disabled={!canPrepareReview()}
  >
```

I try to use something like this

```
  <Button
    disabled={loading || master || Object.keys(assetsSelected).length === 0}
  >
```

but it does not work So any ideas on how it can be improved?

Comment: Your question might be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The expressions are not equivalent.

Comment: The first method was a better way of doing things. Keep your logic separate from your UI markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function evaluates:

```
loading || Object.keys(assets).length !== 0 || master
```

But in the first `disabled` attribute, the function result is negated, so we evaluate:

```
!(loading || Object.keys(assets).length !== 0 || master)
```

If you put that as expression in the `disabled` attribute, it should give equivalent behaviour as in the function-based solution.

However, defining the function is actually better practice. Don't bloat attributes with complex expressions.